# styled-components - test createGlobalStyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

How is it possible to make snapshot tests with styled-components createGlobalStyle?

Tests are running with jest v22.4.4, and styled-components v4.1.2, react v16.7 and jest-styled-components v5.0.1 and react-test-renderer v16.6.3

The output of the snapshot is without the css. but I need a way to test if the css had changes...

E.g.

```
const BaseCSS = createGlobalStyle`
  a { color: red };
`;
```

And a test

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import 'jest-styled-components';

import { BaseCSS } from '../src';

test('test if e', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<div><BaseCSS /> Test</div>).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

edit:

The output of the snapshot looks like: (there is no css in the snapshot)

```
exports[`test if e 1`] = `
  <div>
     Test
  </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/232#issuecomment-639346577) and it works!
The global style component will "live" in the <head> tag, not inside the <body> so "you should have aimed for the head".

Here is my working example:

```
import "jest-styled-components";
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import GlobalStyle from "../../src/styles/GlobalStyle.js";

it("should have global style", () => {
  renderer.create(<GlobalStyle />);
  expect(document.head).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```